# avrdude: /dev/ttyACM0 issue with changing permissions

Tags: usb, permissions, udev, arduino

I was using Arduino IDE on my Arch Linux laptop without problems, after some time /months I'm not able to upload the sketch because of permissions:

`avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyACM0": Permission denied`

I can access and write to the device with `minicom` without problems, because permissions are good:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root uucp
```

My user is in the `uucp` group. But when I start sketch uploading, regarding to the `dmesg`, the usb device is being reconnected and in that moment I can see different permissions:

```
rw------- 1 root root
```

And after some time (seconds) permissions are back as they were. `dmesg` output here:

```
[  313.042695] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  313.253085] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  313.352387] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[  321.234517] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  321.439445] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  321.541392] cdc_acm 2-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
...
```

I've tried to solve that with several custom udev rules, but without success:

```
SUBSYSTEMS="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}== "2341", GROUP="uucp", MODE="0666"
KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", SYMLINK+="%k", GROUP="uucp", MODE="0666"
```

How to force group or mode from the first moment when appeared in the system? I hope this is not just a bug in the Arduino 1.8.3. Kernel version 4.11.9-1-ARCH.

**EDIT #1**:

I found that usb reconnection behavior occurs after exiting `minicom` too,  but in case of `avrdude` this is problem because it is happening when program needs to access the device.

Screencast [here](https://youtu.be/SAI08E65x5c)

**EDIT #2**:

After some time I came back to this issue and I found I have problem just with `ttyACM0` (Yun/Micro/etc. connected with microUSB cable) and `ttyUSB0` (Uno connected with USB-B) is ok. But even this is interesting clue I can't figure it out.

I'm monitoring the rights on the tty devices:

```
watch -n 0.1 'ls -la /dev/ttyUSB* /dev/ttyACM*'
```

- when uploading to `ttyUSB0` just the date/time is changing and everything is working
- when uploading to `ttyACM0` device disappeared for a moment then a new one with wrong rights (and `root:root`) has been created, upload failed and then right are set properly by udev (with `root:uucp`)  ... and then another one cycle (disappear-wrong-correct)

My user is in the `lock` and `uucp` groups, I've tried to add some udev rules or disable them but without success ...

I'm for 99% sure this is something before udev rule is touching it.

Comment: have you ever tried adding the changing permissions command on /etc/rc.local? this script is called at the end of the boot sequence. This script is executed with root permission so you should be able to chmod the ACM0 device

Comment: AFAIK there is no rc.local in ArchLinux but even this can't prevent `avrdude` from resetting port upon the upload.

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but I think you can find somethin here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/User:Herodotus/Rc-Local-Systemd

Comment: I know that there is still pending the avrdude, I'm going to take a look on that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I removed the tlp package and this problem is gone.